# getting certain number of info to antd table

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, antd

i'm new react hooks developer , i dont know much about classes, started with hooks since everybody suggested, here i have antd table(took it from their page, everything is coded using react classes, i somehow converted it to hooks), here i want to give user possibility to choose how many informtion he/she wants in a page.
when user clicks that, it should give dropdown list (10 / page, 20 / page, 50 / page, 100 / page ) from dropdown user can choose how many he wants to be visible... so i want that functionality as it is in the picture

[image]
how to have functionality like that with react hooks ?

here my code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { EventTable } from "./EventTable";

const eventsData = [
  {
    key: "1",
    title: "John Brown",
    age: 32,
    address: "New York No. 1 Lake Park",
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    title: "Joe Black",
    age: 42,
    address: "London No. 1 Lake Park",
  },
  {
    key: "3",
    title: "Jim Green",
    age: 32,
    address: "Sidney No. 1 Lake Park",
  },
  {
    key: "4",
    title: "Jim Red",
    age: 32,
    address: "London No. 2 Lake Park",
  },
  {
    key: "5",
    title: "Jim Red",
    age: 32,
    address: "London No. 2 Lake Park",
  },
];

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <EventTable eventsData={eventsData} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Table } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
const EventTable = ({ eventsData }) => {
  const allColumns = [
    {
      title: "ID",
      dataIndex: "key",
      key: "id",
    },
    {
      title: "Title",
      dataIndex: "title",
      key: "title",
    },
    {
      title: "Address",
      dataIndex: "address",
      key: "address",
    },
    {
      title: "Age",
      dataIndex: "age",
      key: "age",
    },
  ];

  const [tableColumns, setTableColumns] = useState(allColumns);

  return (
    <Table dataSource={eventsData} columns={tableColumns} pagination={true} />
  );
};

export { EventTable };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can **read the code** used for the example, there's a code tab under each component variant, there's also a link to a sandbox, they are really helpful.

I can see that you are sending a boolean to the pagination flag. What about sending an **object** like they do?

```
const pagination = { 
    defaultPageSize: 3,
    current: 1,
    pageSizeOptions: ['3', '6', '9']
}
```

And then sending it to the **Table**.

```
<Table dataSource={eventsData} columns={tableColumns} pagination={pagination} />
```

Another detail, you are a **React developer**, hooks allow us to use `Class` components features, inside functional components, we can also write our own custom hooks, but they are they are just a feature, you are not a *"React Hook dev"*.

[React Hooks](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Comment: do you mean this 'pagination={true}', i can take it away and it still works, how to send an object to that in react hooks, could you give an example using my code ?

Comment: Hello @waleedd32, of course. First of all, it's not "React hooks", you are using React and you are also using React Hooks, I'll edit my answer for a more detailed explanaiton.
And I pasted it in the code above, you should declare a variable, like: const pagination = THE_OBJECT_I_WROTE. I'll edit my answer so it's better explained.

Comment: thanks for response, i have updated photo above maybe it helps to understand better what i want